# How to get/return an Integer Array from a Runnable run() method, having a while loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, runnable

I have a Class Looper that returns an Integer array as follow:

```
public class Looper implements Runnable{

    public AtomicBoolean keepRunning;

    public Looper() {
        keepRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    }

    public void stop() {
        keepRunning.set(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            .
        .
        .
            while (keepRunning.get()) {


                    int[] A = ..... ;                    

            }

    }

}
```

`int[] A` will have a different values after every while loop iteration.
Now say there is another method in the same class as `saveReturnValue` which will store the integer array after every execution of while loop and perform some operations on it. 
But due to `void` nature of `Runnable`, I am unable to get value of A in the other methods.
Is there any way to access `int[] A` outside of this method?

Comment: Even if `run()` weren't void, you'd only be able to return a value once. Perhaps you're looking for some kind of queue that other threads can read? Seems like a basic producer/consumer situation.

Comment: Yes, So is there any way to get it? Thanks though..!!

Comment: Like I said. Queue. Producer/consumer.

Comment: Okay, let me try that..

Comment: Hey, I am not getting it correctly. Can you please post the Queue-Producer/consumer version for above code?

Comment: It's too broad, but the internet is filled with examples.

Comment: Can you post most accurate link for to which I can refer; because the one that I referred is not working.

Comment: I don't have an accurate link. Google has millions of links though.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you can google for "Java Producer Consumer Queue example" and then fix that code to your needs.

General idea is to use a datastructure from which one thread is reading and other is writing, like below.

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<int[]> queue;

    public Producer(LinkedBlockingQueue<int[]> queue) { this.queue = queue;} 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning.get()) {
                int[] a = ..... ;                    
                queue.add(a);
        }
     }

public class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<int[]> queue;

    public Consumer(LinkedBlockingQueue<int[]> queue) { this.queue = queue;} 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning.get()) {
             int[] a = queue.take(a);
             saveValue(a);
        }
     }

public class MainOrWhatever {
     public void whateverMethod {
         LinkedBlockingQueue<int[]> theQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<int[]>();
         Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);
         Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
         executorService.submit(consumer);
         executorService.submit(producer);
         ...
     }
}
```